# Is there way to build variable value based on another variable value in application.yaml?

Tags: spring-boot, properties, yaml

Let's say I have following **application.yaml**:

```
my:
  key1: key1Value
  key2: key2Value
  key3: key1 + _ + key2
```

It is an attemp to assign the property `my.key3="key1Value_key2Value"`

But it doesn't work.

Is there way in spring-boot to have such kind of references in application.yml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use property placeholders in the `application.yaml` as follows:

```
my:
  key1: key1Value
  key2: key2Value
  key3: ${my.key1}_${my.key2}
```